# Kendo Datepicker Validation Failed for different browser and PC

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I was create a page has Datepicker with dd/MM/yyyy format with culture ar-SA but when I try to set the date it's always returns invalid date here is the datepicker

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
                .Name("ReviewDate")
              .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")              
                )
```

The validation is always failed on form submit in some system. I have set culture to my JS document ready to  kendo.culture("en-GB");

My Model is:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DataMember(Name = "ReviewDate")]
        [AllowHtml]
        [DisplayName("Review Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ReviewDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the culture and update the validator to satisfy the client-side validation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  kendo.culture("en-GB");
  $.validator.addMethod('date',
      function (value, element) {
          return this.optional(element) || kendo.parseDate(value)
      });
});
```

Also set your server culture too so it's the same by adding the following to your web.config under `<system.web>`

```
 <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" enableClientBasedCulture="true" ></globalization>
```

I've used `en-GB` but you can swap that out for other cultures e.g. `ar-SA` if you want to use that instead